# Clockwise sorting segments of a polygons

Tags: python, mathematics, spatial-sort

My polygons are divised into an array of lines features. Each segments have only 2 coordinates. I would like to sort those segments clockwise starting from the top-right (north-east) like in the image below

[image]

I have the starting and ending coordinates of each segments. Is there a mathematical function that could sort them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074984/sorting-according-to-clockwise-point-coordinates/51075469#51075469

Comment: are your polygons guaranteed to be convex, and not more convoluted and wiggly like curling in on themselves?

Comment: @Spacedman no they are not always convex...

Comment: Maybe something like merge lines, convert to polygon, extract verices and use vertex index, starting with the one with max. x/y value